# Reading MYSQL Db using python returns me a tuple which i need to convert to list

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

After connecting python to MySQL Db, i ran a query to extract data from MySQL using group_concat and group by, and then i fetchall.

The output looks like this:

```
[('Fun,Wonderful,Good,Salty',)]
```

But i want it to look like this instead:

```
['Fun','Wonderful','Good','Salty']
```

Fetchall seems to be returning some sort of tuple and it is quite annoying as i need it as a list to be used in python. I tried using list comprehension to replace the comma (,) with quote&comma&quote (',') but it changes to this instead:

```
["Fun','Wonderful','Good','Salty"]
```

It changes the start and end quote to be opposite of what i want to replace. How do i get what i want?

Why is the group concat not being able to immediately output this:

```
['Fun','Wonderful','Good','Salty']
```

but instead output some list tuple sort which requires me to convert to a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You instruct MySQL to return the values of the group as a comma-separated string in one result field by using `group_concat`. Python cannot know that you need the string split into individual fields again.

The return value of a `fetchall()` is defined to be a sequence of sequences as per the [DB API 2.0 specification in PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchall). Representing the query result as a list of tuples is the commonly accepted practice.

If you just want to see one element of the result, you can use [`fetchone()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) which will return a single sequence, it might be a tuple though, depending on the driver you use.

If you need that string as a list in Python, you can get one using this, for example:

```
[('Fun,Wonderful,Good,Salty',)][0][0].split(',')
# ['Fun', 'Wonderful', 'Good', 'Salty']
```